# VMWare installation not working

Tags: vmware

Have installed VMWare trial (latest version) onto a fresh Ubuntu installation but when I try to run it, a dialog appears:

"Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernal."

When I click the "Install" button an updater dialog appears with

```
Stopping VMware Services (+ green tick)
Virtual Machine Monitor (+ red exclamation)
Virtual Network Device (+ red exclamation)
Running depmod (+ green tick)
Starting VMware Services (+ red no-entry sign)
```

Then another dialog:

```
Unable to start services.
See log file /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-2939.log for details.
```

I can obviously see what the file is saying about missing files etc. but what should I do about it?

Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Log file:

```
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=32127 version=11.0.0 build=build-2305329 option=Release
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: The process is 64-bit.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: Host is Linux 4.8.0-36-generic Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2017-03-20T12:27:23.027Z| vthread-4| I120: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.061Z| vthread-4| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-32127.log
2017-03-20T12:27:23.066Z| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.066Z| vthread-4| I120: Created new pathsHash.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.066Z| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 4.8.0-36-generic to "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.066Z| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.066Z| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-03-20T12:27:23.066Z| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.066Z| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-03-20T12:27:23.071Z| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.071Z| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-03-20T12:27:23.174Z| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers
2017-03-20T12:27:23.174Z| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.189Z| vthread-4| I120: Read 20864 symbol versions
2017-03-20T12:27:23.189Z| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.189Z| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.189Z| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.189Z| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.189Z| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.189Z| vthread-4| I120: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.189Z| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.191Z| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.191Z| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.192Z| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.192Z| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.193Z| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.193Z| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.194Z| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.194Z| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.195Z| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.205Z| vthread-4| I120: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2017-03-20T12:27:23.205Z| vthread-4| I120: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2017-03-20T12:27:23.217Z| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.217Z| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 4.8.0-36-generic to "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.217Z| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.217Z| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-03-20T12:27:23.217Z| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.217Z| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-03-20T12:27:23.222Z| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.222Z| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-03-20T12:27:23.324Z| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers
2017-03-20T12:27:23.324Z| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.339Z| vthread-4| I120: Read 20864 symbol versions
2017-03-20T12:27:23.339Z| vthread-4| I120: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include
2017-03-20T12:27:23.339Z| vthread-4| I120: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include
2017-03-20T12:27:23.339Z| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.339Z| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-03-20T12:27:23.339Z| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.339Z| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-03-20T12:27:23.344Z| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.344Z| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-03-20T12:27:23.344Z| vthread-4| I120: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2017-03-20T12:27:23.346Z| vthread-4| I120: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.346Z| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.346Z| vthread-4| I120: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.348Z| vthread-4| I120: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.348Z| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.351Z| vthread-4| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.351Z| vthread-4| I120: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.351Z| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.351Z| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.351Z| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-03-20T12:27:23.351Z| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.351Z| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-03-20T12:27:23.355Z| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.355Z| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-03-20T12:27:23.355Z| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.355Z| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.355Z| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-03-20T12:27:23.355Z| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.355Z| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-03-20T12:27:23.359Z| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.359Z| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-03-20T12:27:23.360Z| vthread-4| I120: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.360Z| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.360Z| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 4.8.0-36-generic to "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.360Z| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.360Z| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-03-20T12:27:23.360Z| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.360Z| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-03-20T12:27:23.364Z| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.364Z| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-03-20T12:27:23.467Z| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers
2017-03-20T12:27:23.467Z| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.482Z| vthread-4| I120: Read 20864 symbol versions
2017-03-20T12:27:23.482Z| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.484Z| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-03-20T12:27:23.484Z| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2017-03-20T12:27:23.485Z| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-03-20T12:27:24.061Z| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2017-03-20T12:27:24.061Z| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2017-03-20T12:27:24.066Z| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2017-03-20T12:27:24.066Z| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j8 -C /tmp/modconfig-9nzoQQ/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2017-03-20T12:27:24.882Z| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2017-03-20T12:27:24.883Z| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2017-03-20T12:27:24.883Z| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2017-03-20T12:27:24.888Z| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2017-03-20T12:27:24.888Z| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j8 -C /tmp/modconfig-9nzoQQ/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2017-03-20T12:27:29.630Z| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Comment: Are you running VMWare as root? You shouldn't. The error message says `Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences"`.

Comment: Not deliberately, I'm just clicking the icon and the rest is just happening, as described. How should I do it differently?

Comment: Fixed it - I re-installed and it worked fine! No idea what was wrong first time.

Comment: @pauljohn32 Was it 'ill-posed'? It was a problem when I asked it, the solution was to re-install. Seems pretty valid to me.

Comment: This question was already asked and answered. <a href="https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138403/vmware-15-not-working-on-ubuntu-19-04/1140149#1140149"> ORIGINAL LINK </a>

Comment: @AndrewYu True except my question was earlier by 2 years. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

This is a script.

```
#!/bin/bash

#make sure you have git. if you don't, run: sudo apt-get install git

#copy and paste this code into a .sh file. e.g. vmwareFix.sh

#run: chmod 744 <filename.sh, e.g. vmwareFix.sh> 

#then run this file: /path/to/this/script

VMWARE_VERSION=workstation-15.0.4

TMP_FOLDER=/tmp/patch-vmware

rm -fdr $TMP_FOLDER

mkdir -p $TMP_FOLDER

cd $TMP_FOLDER

git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git

cd $TMP_FOLDER/vmware-host-modules

git checkout $VMWARE_VERSION

git fetch

make

sudo make install

sudo rm /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1

sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1

/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1

sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

Comment: Since this wasn't marked as the solution I just want to say that this worked perfectly for me.