# VMware 15 not working on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: vmware

I have upgraded Ubuntu 19.04 from 18.04 version. After upgradation of the OS, VMware 15 stopped working. I have reinstalled the VMware 15, but still its giving "VMware Kernal Module Updater" popup with message "Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into running kernel". After clicking on the install button it shows the error that it can start the services.
can anyone let me know how to get this resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Milo83! I also have this problem and the code below worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

#make sure you have git. if you don't, run: sudo apt-get install git

#copy and paste this code into a .sh file. e.g. vmwareFix.sh

#run: chmod 744 <filename.sh, e.g. vmwareFix.sh> 

#then run this file: /path/to/this/script

VMWARE_VERSION=workstation-15.0.4

TMP_FOLDER=/tmp/patch-vmware

rm -fdr $TMP_FOLDER

mkdir -p $TMP_FOLDER

cd $TMP_FOLDER

git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git

cd $TMP_FOLDER/vmware-host-modules

git checkout $VMWARE_VERSION

git fetch

make

sudo make install

sudo rm /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1

sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1

/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1

sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

The instructions are in the comments above. Bye.

Comment: It is important to change the VMWARE_VERSION variable to your actual product and version.

Comment: @variona Yes. \

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have done as per the instructions. After running it shows, Virtual  machine monitor failed and Virtual ethernet failed.

Comment: @Milo83 could you give me the details? I'll see.

Comment: @Milo83 You might want to _reinstall_ your **Ubuntu 19.04** rather than upgrading it from old versions.

Comment: fyi: The build-number is not needed (in case you are wondering as I was, when i read you had to change the build number) 

thanks a lot for posting this here!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!